# Batch file with C# console app, how to stop the .bat file from excuting?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch file. I also have a C# CONSOLE APP that checks whether a certain set of files exist in a certain directory.
what I need is: If the files are present then continue to run the next steps in the  `.bat` file. Otherwise EXIT.

I need some help with how the console app can talk to the `.bat` file ( you know what I mean ) and then stop the rest of the `.bat` file from running if the input files were not present.

Comment: Does the console app make use of [return codes](https://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html)?

Comment: Why don't you check if the files exist in the bat file instead?

Comment: Youre problably missuing the bat file. But have if the apps checks the files once you may return not Zero, if the files don't exists. And catch that exit code?

Comment: Please provide some code that you have already tested. We aren't a code writing site, we are hear to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

It's really unclear what you are asking for, however let me try to answer. I believe you want to continue the program is "some files" exist, otherwise you will exit the console app.

Assuming these files are somewhere which you can access consistently through a directory, and their path won't be changing, you could use the following code

```
string pathToFiles = @"C:/Users/YOUR_USER/"; //wherever

string[] fileNames = { "wordDocument.docx", "application.exe", "list.txt" }; //etc

static void Main()
{
    foreach (string file in fileNames)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(pathToFiles, file)))
        {
            continueTheProgram();
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(-1); //-1 can signify that the file does not exist
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm noticing that you mention a batch file. Why not just have the Console App do all the work, rather than bouncing between the two?